# Translating NSEvent from Objective-C to Lua

Tags: objective-c, lua

I'm currently trying to read the contents of an Apple-made plist file using Lua, so that I can use it's values for something.

The plist contains keyboard shortcuts, using a 'modifierMask'.

By testing one by one, I've determined that the below modifierMask values match the listed modifier keys - but I'm unsure of how exactly Apple is calculating the mask value:

```
-- modifierMask = 131072    (shift)
-- modifierMask = 262144    (control)
-- modifierMask = 524288    (option)
-- modifierMask = 1048576   (command)           
-- modifierMask = 786432    (control + option)
-- modifierMask = 393216    (control + shift)
-- modifierMask = 1310720   (control + command)         
-- modifierMask = 1572864   (option + command)
-- modifierMask = 655360    (shift + option)
-- modifierMask = 1179648   (command + shift)
-- modifierMask = 917504    (control + shift + option)
-- modifierMask = 1703936   (option + command + shift)
-- modifierMask = 1835008   (control + option + command)
```

Someone else has suggested that most likely the modifier masks match up to the [NSEvent modifier flags](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsevent/modifier_flags), and supplied the following Objective-C example:

```
Modifier Flags
The following constants (except for NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask)     represent device-independent bits found in event modifier flags:

Declaration
OBJECTIVE-C
enum {
   NSAlphaShiftKeyMask = 1 << 16,
   NSShiftKeyMask      = 1 << 17,
   NSControlKeyMask    = 1 << 18,
   NSAlternateKeyMask  = 1 << 19,
   NSCommandKeyMask    = 1 << 20,
   NSNumericPadKeyMask = 1 << 21,
   NSHelpKeyMask       = 1 << 22,
   NSFunctionKeyMask   = 1 << 23,
   NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask = 0xffff0000U 
};
```

This looks promising, however I know nothing about Objective-C, so I was just wondering if anyone could please help me translate these Objective-C declarations into something I can use within Lua? Basically I want to create a Lua function that inputs a modifierMask (i.e. '131072') and returns a result that tells me what that modifierMask means (i.e. 'shift'). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with"?  Are you looking for a way to convert the shift values into integers?  Or are you looking for a way to use those values to compare the numbers in the plist?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. Basically I want to create a function that allows me to input a modifierMask (i.e. 131072) from the plist, and return it's value (i.e. shift button pressed).

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/1021#issuecomment-251827969):

```
maskToTable = function(value)
local modifiers = {
    AlphaShift = 1 << 16,
    Shift      = 1 << 17,
    Control    = 1 << 18,
    Alternate  = 1 << 19,
    Command    = 1 << 20,
    NumericPad = 1 << 21,
    Help       = 1 << 22,
    Function   = 1 << 23,
}

local answer = {}

for k, v in pairs(modifiers) do
    if (value & v) == v then
        table.insert(answer, k)
    end
end

return answer
end
```